# Spring mongodb query nested array containing nested arrays

Tags: java, mongodb, kotlin, spring-data

i have these 3 class

```
@Document(collection = "Countries")
class CountryDoc
{
    @Id
    lateinit var id : String

    var name : String = ""

    var governorates : ArrayList<Governorate> = ArrayList()

}

class Governorate
{
    var id : String = ""

    var name : String = ""

    var cardinalPoint : CardinalPoint = CardinalPoint.SOUTH_WEST

    var cities : ArrayList<City> = ArrayList()
}

class City
{
    var id : String = ""

    var name : String = ""
}
```

and i want to get the full address of a city, the result must be like this

```
{
  "countryId" : ""
  "countryName" : "",
  "governorateId" : "",
  "governorateName" : "",
  "cardinalPoint" : ""
  "cityId" : "",
  "cityName" : ""
}
```

i tried this query but it did not work, I had only the information of the country

```
    val countryCriteria = Criteria.where("id").`is`(countryId)
    val governorateCriteria = Criteria.where("id").`is`(governorateId)
    val cityCriteria = Criteria.where("id").`is`(cityId)

    val aggregation = Aggregation.newAggregation(
        Aggregation.match(countryCriteria),
        Aggregation.project().and("id").`as`("countryId").and("name").`as`("countryName"),
        Aggregation.unwind("governorates"),
        Aggregation.match(governorateCriteria),
 Aggregation.project().and("name").`as`("governorateName").and("id").`as`("governorateId").and("cardinalPoint").`as`("cardinalPoint")
        Aggregation.unwind("cities"),
        Aggregation.match(cityCriteria)
        Aggregation.project().and("name").`as`("cityName").and("id").`as`("cityId")
    )

val result = mongoDb.aggregate(aggregation, CountryDoc::class.java, Address::class.java).uniqueMappedResult
```

i can't understand why that does not works for me, can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can get inspired from this query I write on Mongoshell:

the query can be tested on [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/)

```js
db.city.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "_id": "c1"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "governate",
      "as": "governates",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "cities"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "governate": {
        $arrayElemAt: [
          "$governates",
          0
        ]
      },
      "cityName": "$name"
    }
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "country",
      "as": "coutries",
      "localField": "governate._id",
      "foreignField": "governates"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "country": {
        $arrayElemAt: [
          "$coutries",
          0
        ]
      },
      "cityName": 1,
      "governateName": "$governate.name",
      "governateId": "$governate._id"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "_id": 0,
      "cityId": "$_id",
      "countryName": "$country.name",
      "countryId": "$country._id",
      "cityName": 1,
      "governateId": 1,
      "governateName": 1
    }
  }
])
```

The data I used looks like this:

```
db={
  "country": [
    {
      "_id": "1",
      "name": "country",
      "governates": [
        "g1"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "governate": [
    {
      "_id": "g1",
      "name": "governate",
      "cities": [
        "c1"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "city": [
    {
      "_id": "c1",
      "name": "city"
    }
  ]
}
```